# Divider disappears from last item in listview if footerview added

Tags: android, listview, divider

If footer view added in ListView, then divider disappears from last item of ListView.

Even I have set `android:footerDividersEnabled="true"` with ListView and my footer view is just TextTiew.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `ListView` implementation in Android never draws dividers between items that are disabled, which if you are just calling the `addFooterView(View v)` method then by default your footer will be.

Instead you need to call the `addFooterView(View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)` method with `isSelectable` set to `true`. You can just pass `null` for the `data` object if you don't need it.

Comment: Yes, added a footerView like this: listView.addFooterView(view, null, true) , and it worked fine... thanks

Comment: this adds the divider, but introduces a worse problem. now the footer is clickable!

Answer (score 21):

Setting `isSelectable` to `true` didn't work for me, maybe because I was also calling `removeFooterView` when my list was done loading.

What finally fixed it for me was setting `android:layout_height` to "`fill_parent`" instead of "`wrap_content`" on the ListView.

Comment: setting 'android:layout_height="fill_parent"' does the trick... thank u so much for the solution!!!!

Comment: Awesome thanks! just noting for future users, use match_parent for forward compatibility. Don't know when fill_parent will be deprecated

Answer (score 14):

This almost worked for me.  I was after a divider after the last list item, but not after the footer as my footer was empty space.  I ended up adding two footers, one selectable of zero height and one not selectable containing the padding.

```
TextView view = new TextView(this);
view.setLines(0);
TextView view1 = new TextView(this);
view1.setLines(4);
mListView.addFooterView(view, null, true);
mListView.addFooterView(view1, null, false);
mListView.setFooterDividersEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try setting the `layout_height` of the `ListView` to `match_parent`:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:divider="#333333"
android:dividerHeight="1px"
```

When the `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content` it might skip the bottom divider:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="#333333"
android:dividerHeight="1px"
```

Answer (score 1):

Head through the wall approach, but reliable, is to manually add divider as a footer view.

```
ListView myListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);
myListView.addFooterView(getInflater().inflate(R.layout.horizontal_divider, myListView, false), null, false);
myListView.addFooterView(getInflater().inflate(R.layout.the_original_footer_view, myListView, false), null, false);
```

Where the layout file would look like this:

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1px"
    android:background="?android:attr/dividerVertical" />
```

This approach can be used to add the divider easily even after the last footer, regardless it is selectable, enabled or anything - it just stays there.

Note the height is `1px` rather than `1dp`. Though against all recommendations, at least at the device I tested this gives the same divider height as ListView, while `1dp` does not.