# ViewList item divider as Progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar, divider

I would like to add an "ProgressBar" (like the one in Chrome for Android when you load a new webpage) to a List Item which will show the progress in the current lesson. (It's about an app for School, which all schedules).

Currently I have (Screenshot a bit outdated, I have managed to get the last divider with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17882477/1508634) fix):

[image]

You see on the screenshot after every item an divider, a gray line. I would like to replace this one with an progressbar (Not all dividers, just one. The same progressbar as Chrome for Android, when you load a new webpage). How I'm able to do this?

My current ScheduleAdapter:

```
package nl.devapp.ictcollege.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import nl.devapp.ictcollege.R;
import nl.devapp.ictcollege.models.Schedule;

public class ScheduleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Schedule> items;

    public ScheduleAdapter(Context context, List<Schedule> list) {
        this.items = list;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (this.items == null || this.items.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return this.items.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Schedule getItem(int position) {
        return this.items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            view = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_schedule, null);

        Schedule item = this.getItem(position);

        TextView number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_number);
        TextView lesson = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_lesson);
        TextView to = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_to);
        TextView classRoom = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_class_room);

        number.setText(Integer.toString(item.getHour()));
        lesson.setText(item.getLesson());
        to.setText(item.getTo());
        classRoom.setText(item.getClassRoom());

        return view;
    }
}
```

and my FragmentSchedule xml (where I create the ListView):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="nl.devapp.ictcollege.fragments.SelectFragment">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rooster_list"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/last_sync"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my row_schedule:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_class_room"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_lesson"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_number" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's impossible to have different dividers for different list items (you set the divider to the whole `ListView`, not the items themselves). 
I'd just put a `ProgressBar` in your `row_schedule`, set it's visibility to `gone`. In your adapter's getView mthod you check if the row is the one you want to show the ProgressBar in and set it's visibility to `visible`. Keep a reference to the `ProgressBar` and update it with the progress.

EDIT: Other possibility: Create a layout that contains only a `ProgressBar`. If the item that you want to display the `ProgressBar` under is at index 3 in your list, in `getView()` for position 4 you inflate the `ProgressBar` layout instead of your normal list item layout and return the view. 
In `getCount()` you have to return the number of your items + 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. I would like to have a progressbar as Chrome for Android, when you load a new page under the ActionBar. But now, not under the actionbar but under an listitem. Note: Information added to the post.

Comment: Added another possibility.

Comment: Thank you, the other possibility fixed it! :)